# DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2, connection-string

I have an SSIS package where Source: IBM DB2, Target: SQL Server.
I have created a package in SSIS and able to run perfectly in my local machine. All connections work perfectly, data populates in the target tables.
However, after deploying it to SQL Server the package fails with following error in screenshot. Checked the server it has IBM OLEDB drivers for DB2 installed in it. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19547/5203?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows:

> SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file
> system.

This is not a programming matter, it is only configuration. The message  means that the configuration (of the Db2 product on your SSIS hostname) is either not yet started, or has not yet been finished.

You can do the configuration with either a GUI, or via command-lines.
This work must be done on the hostname where the data-source is required (e.g. on the SSIS environment).

For a GUI: Use remote desktop to that SSIS environment, and then use the `odbcad32` tool. Notice that there can be both a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version of `odbcad32`, so use the correct bitness to match the SSIS and Db2-driver bitness. Use `odbcad32` to create and configure the data-source for the Db2-database. Usually that means creating and configuring a System data source. You can also test connectivity to the DSN from within odbcad32.  The act of using odbcad32 to create the data source will (under the covers) cause the Db2 "database directory" to be created.

You can also do this configuration via either command-line actions (if the relevant Db2 tools are on the PATH, see `db2 catalog tcpip node` , `db2 catalog database`,  `db2 catalog system data source` commands ), or alternatively by populating an XML file called `db2dsdriver.cfg`(which the Db2 driver interprets at runtime). All of these commands and configuration files are fully described in the free Db2 Knowledge Centre online.